# Omnet++ framework and linking Crypto++

Tags: omnet++, crypto++

Can you help me with the steps to link/import Crypto++ library to OMNeT++ framework properly, please.

I use OMNeT++ 5.0/inetmanet 3.0 version (Windows 10).

Comment: Perhaps you should ask on an OMNeT++ mailing list. It seems like the OMNeT++ folks would know best how to configure their library. They can probably point you to the tutorial you are seeking. One of the reasons you seem to be having trouble is you asking for instructions without making effort. On the other mailing list you don't state the steps you performed and where you encountered trouble. You simply state it doesn't work and you ask for the tutorial.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. i found 3 methods to import the library. i asked the omnet++/crypto++ community to how link library properly. i had no answer until now.

Comment: When i want to import Crypto++ folder(or zip file), i found the Omnet++ wizard :

https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-IF1_CTuixaI/V9BPRjVt03I/AAAAAAAAAPI/8i9Ms2oVbjU26hrcsL3lpvh1y-HIsR6LQCLcB/s1600/omnet%252B%252B%2Bimport.png              Please help me to choose the right choice.

Comment: I can't speak for everyone at Crypto++, but I'm guessing no one knows OMNeT++. I have no idea what the program is or what it does (I'm guessing it may be a development environment). Linking libraries is CompSci 101. People do it all the time with libraries like OpenSSL and Pthreads. The folks on OMNeT++ should be telling you how to link libraries into programs from their environment.

Answer (score 0):

OMNeT++ on windows is a C++ simulation library that is built in MinGW environment with GCC (on windows). As such, everything that applies to a general program applies here. You need to have the crypto++ headers in the /tools/win32/mingw32/include folder, the libraries in the tools/win32/mingw32/lib and the dll in the bin directory...

You may be able to install the library and the headers with:

```
pacman -Su mingw-w64-i686-crypto++
```

After that you can just use the include file of the library as usual. You have to add the crypto library to the linker command line (in the IDE: Project / Properties and add the library in the "Makemake" dialog on the Libraries tab.